# Creating a "scrapbook" node type using an entity reference field

Tags: 7, entities

I'm building a site that includes two node types, "scrapbook" and "press clipping". A user can create multiple scrapbooks which are either public or private, and they can also add press clippings to a public pool.

Each scrapbook includes an entity reference field that allows multiple press clippings to be referenced from each notebook. This works fine, but the only way I can add a reference from a notebook to a press clipping is by editing the scrapbook. I want to include a dropdown on each press clipping that allows the user to select one of the scrapbooks they have created and add the press clipping to that scrapbook.

What's the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: quick search gives this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-implement-two-way-node-references

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd move the entity relationship field to the press clipping content type, so you get the convenient dropdown there, and use the reverse relationship, or contextual filter when building a view

Comment: Great, thanks! But how do I allow users to add a clipping to a scrapbook from the node view screen, rather than from the node edit screen?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to address the fact that I want to set up node references for each user, rather than having one global node reference?

Comment: For the first problem, you can put the add form into a block, and add it to the page using the block system, context, panels, or a block insertion module. here's a brief how-to on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450941/inserting-a-form-into-a-block-in-drupal . For the second problem, I've used the entity_reference_view widget and created a simple view with a contextual filter linked to the current user id as a quick fix. https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget